# Не работает функция по нахождению факториала

Tags: java, алгоритм, математика

По заданию нужно было написать функцию которая находит факториал числа. Если факториал меньше нуля, или больше 12 - выбросить IllegalArgumentException.
При тестирование кода происходит что-то непонятное, прошу указать на мою ошибку.

```
public class Factorial {
int factorial = 1;

public int factorial(int n) {
if(n < 0 || n > 12) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException();
} else if(n == 0) {
  return 1;
}

for(int i = n; i < 2; i--) {
  factorial *= i;
}

return factorial;
}
}
```

Comment: `factorial = 1; for(int i = n; i > 1; i--) { factorial *= i; }`

Comment: Благодарю за правку, добавьте пожалуйста ответ, что бы я мог его отметить как решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, опечатка в `for`:

```
factorial = 1; 
for(int i = n; i > 1; i--) { 
  factorial *= i; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = n; i < 2; i--) {
  factorial *= i;
}
```

То есть, начиная со значения `n`, пока оно меньше 2, уменьшать...
Вы точно этого хотите? :)

Я бы делал

```
for(int i = n; i >= 2; i--) {
  factorial *= i;
}
```

Comment: Моя глупость, совсем забыл принцип работы условия в этом цикле =)